# Displaying optional feature in Azure Cloud Service website based on datetime

Tags: datetime, azure, gmt

I would like to deploy a change to my Azure cloud service website, that will put a small feature live from 9am on Tuesday 2nd April.

The cloud service is hosted in West Europe.

So I started with just a small line of code around the feature:

*MVC Razor code:*

```
 @if (DateTime.Now >= new DateTime(2014, 4, 1, 9, 00, 0))
```

Meaning if it is after 1st April at 9:00am, show the feature.

This works fine in my dev environment messing around with todays date and the current time.

What I am not sure about is if this will work in my Azure hosted service, AND take into account the summertime change.

I am aware of UTC and the timezone classes but not sure how to construct this.

Comment: Since all servers in Windows Azure are in UTC timezone, can't you have just one logic that the new feature will be available from some time in UTC? In this case, all users will see the changes at the same time.

Comment: Like I said, I'm aware of UTC, but not sure how to configure the UTC time that matches 9:00 in GMT summer time. I *think* this is what I want to do do: DateTime.UtcNow >= new DateTime(2014, 4, 01, 8, 00, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)